# Calculating time length from a newly created record and then inserting that time into a column in the record?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a database like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bUfl.png

The main table called

"Procedure" can have many rows in the "Procedure_Event" table. Each procedure event row has a column called "time".

This is here so I can be able to calculate the total time from the first row to the last row in that record.

This is what happens:

> -Row in Procedure table created and data is added. -Works
>
> -Procedure event rows are created in "Procedure Event" table and are
>   filled. -Works
>
> -Calculation of time length using the first row and the last row in
>   that record - Not working
>   -Inserting calculated length of time back into the Procedure row column which was created at the start. This column will be called "procedure_length"

Why am I doing this?
This will allow users to find procedures

This is my query:

```
SELECT procedure_id, SUBTIME(events_max.start, events_min.start) AS duration
FROM procedure
JOIN ( SELECT procedure_id, SELECT MAX(time) AS start FROM procedure_events GROUP BY procedure_id ) AS events_max USING ( procedure_id )
JOIN ( SELECT procedure_id, SELECT MIN(time) AS start FROM procedure_events GROUP BY procedure_id ) AS events_min USING ( procedure_id )
GROUP BY procedure_id
```

Should I put this in a stored procedure?

Currently my query is getting error 1064:

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your query:

```
SELECT procedure_id, SELECT MIN(TIME) AS START FROM procedure_events GROUP BY procedure_id
```

This is not good, you use select once per query not for each field you want to retrieve or function you want to compute, so the above would be:

```
SELECT procedure_id, MIN(TIME) AS START FROM procedure_events GROUP BY procedure_id
```

Secondly, TIME and START are reserved words an can not be used as field names (unless enclosed in backticks `` - but this is not a good recomendation).

Always try to keep your queries simplest as possible -this will give you:

- easy maintenance in the future
- readability
- performance benefits

If you just want to calculate the duration of a procedure,  this could give you a starting point:

```
SELECT
  procedure_id,
  TIMEDIFF(MAX(`time`), MIN(`TIME`)) AS duration
FROM procedure_events
GROUP BY procedure_id
```

Then you can insert the computed value into the appropiate table.

Cheers.